# invalid migration numbering type was specified : sequential?

Tags: codeigniter, migration, codeigniter-3

whenever i run codeigniter migration gives me the following error:

> invalid migration numbering type was specified : sequential

in ci_2+ it was running fine then i upgraded to ci_3.02,i also checked ci_3 documentation.
and followed their example also .

```
$config['migration_type']="Sequential";
$config['migration_version']=1;
```

i have one file in migration folder.

001_system_db.php

no effect. help please.

Comment: Did you try the lowercase 'sequential'?

Comment: Yup. @Scorpion [is right](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Migration.php#L161).

Comment: have you tried like this? `001`

Answer (score 1):

thanks [Scorpion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3089345/scorpion) your one and short comments save my day.
i tried lowercase "sequential" and it worked.

```
$config['migration_type']="Sequential";
```

to lowercase

```
$config['migration_type']="sequential";
```

thanks

Comment: Wow! The problem really was the capital S. Thank you.